# How to abort a thread without causing problems

Tags: c#, multithreading

I seem to have something wrong in my C# threading code...

We have a `Report` object that knows how to `ExportToPdf()`.  If I run the code without any threading, everything is fine.  What we're trying to do is run a series of reports (still one at a time), but with the ability to cut off the report export if it takes longer than a certain period of time (hardcoded in my simple example to 100 ms).

```
    public RunningMethod()
    {
        Report myReport = new Report();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Thread reportThread = new Thread(() => DoBackgroundJob(myReport, "test" + i.ToString()));
            reportThread.Start();

            bool finished = reportThread.Join(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
            if (!finished)
            {
                reportThread.Abort();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void DoBackgroundJob(Report myReport, string reportFilename)
    {
        report.ExportToPdf(@"C:\" + reportFilename + ".pdf");
    }
```

Now, I know that Thread.Abort is frowned upon, but I'm not 100% certain that there's another option for us here (the ExportToPdf method isn't ours...it's a 3rd party method).  I've got a question open to them to see if there's a way around that.  But, if there isn't, my problem is this:

When I run this code, I get an error in the export method complaining that the "Thread was being aborted."  This makes sense to me I just aborted the thread, so it's dying.  So is the correct solution to surround the contents of DoBackgroundJob with some kind of try-catch, and just swallow the error?  I feel like this is just getting uglier and uglier.  Is there a better way to deal with this?

Comment: I'm assuming this is C#? You may want to add appropriate language tags so your question gets more views. Regarding your actual question (assuming C#), you might consider using async/await instead of creating threads directly. With async/await you can specify a cancellation token which I think is cleaner than Thread.Abort(). Not sure how that will affect the `ExportToPdf` operation though.

Comment: @E.Moffat Yep, C#...just added that to the question, thanks!  Will look into async/await...I'm new to this arena, so I can't quickly evaluate that suggestion, but it sounds good!