# Why is ThreadAbortException-like exception not being caught

Tags: multithreading, exception

(In case you're interested, the background for this question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36583250/how-to-abort-a-thread-without-causing-problems), but I don't think it's critical for this particular question.)

We're trying to run a series of report exports (a third party method call) one at a time in separate threads, so we can kill off the thread if it takes too long.  The ugly, but best-so-far, idea is to use Thread.Abort to kill the thread exporting a given report, then do a ResetAbort to allow the rest of the code to continue.

The proof of concept code looks like this:

```
public RunningMethod()
{
    Report myReport = new Report();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Thread reportThread = new Thread(() => DoBackgroundJob(myReport, "test" + i.ToString()));
        reportThread.Start();

        bool finished = reportThread.Join(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
        if (!finished)
        {
            reportThread.Abort();
        }
    }
}

protected void DoBackgroundJob(Report myReport, string reportFilename)
{
    try
    {
        report.ExportToPdf(@"C:\" + reportFilename + ".pdf");
    }
    catch (ThreadAbortException)
    {
    }
    break;
}
```

I'm getting a strange result when I run this...the Export line seems to throw an exception that seems like it should be a ThreadAbortException, but apparently is not, since it doesn't get caught by the catch (ThreadAbortException), but is caught by a catch (Exception).

I'd like to know what kind of exception I'm getting, but I can't see it because when I try to view it I only get "Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack."

Is there a way to determine what is happening?  What exception is really being thrown here?

Comment: TAE is special.  Preventing it from being automatically rethrown requires Thread.ResetAbort().  Do keep in mind that you can never call safely call ExportToPdf() again, consider Environment.FailFast() instead.

Comment: @HansPassant I had the Thread.ResetAbort() line in there originally, but I thought it might just confuse the issue.  It doesn't seem to actually affect how the code runs (in this simple example).  I'm confused why I wouldn't be able to specifically call ExportToPdf() again.  If the report is in a bad state (because of something got corrupted) isn't almost everything potentially bad, not just ExportToPdf?  (Maybe that's what you meant).  I should probably rebuild the report in the loop in the case where an abort occurred.